# Maven: Resolve dependencies using container dependencies first

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have a `plugin project` which is added to other `container projects` as a dependency.

Now, this plugin project uses many frequent dependencies like spring-security, commons-lang, etc.

Usually, the container projects contain their own versions of such frequent dependencies. So, when we add our plugin dependency there are conflicts and the dependencies are resolved based on regular `maven dependency resolver` and depending on `scopes` and `optional` tags provided in the plugin project dependencies.

Is there a way where all the dependencies are resolved using the version in parent dependencies first and iff they are not available then use the version specified in plugin dependency.

Note: optional and scope runtime have a problem that these dependencies are provided by the container and thus beats the aim to provide a hassle-free single dependency to add plugin dependency.

Comment: As I understand, you build the plugin once and add it to container projects? So the container projects (poms) are plugin-specific? Or is it the other way round, you build the plugin for each container using its own pom?

Comment: build the plugin once and add it to container projects

Comment: Why does the scope: provided not work for you. You need to adapt each container anyway, if you need additional artifacts for a specific module. Using scope provided in the plugin-project you can add what is necessary, if necessary and in the version necessary.

Comment: Right now I am using scope-provided. Problem with that approach is that the container/projects have to provide these(around 20 in my case) jars explicitly in their projects.

Comment: Are you already using <properties> to define versions? In that case, at least you can override the versions of the components shared with the container by the container project.

Comment: Will think over this and reply. Leaving for the day :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugins pom define the version of a dependency as range of the versions you know the plugin to be able to use. If a container-dependency overlaps this will be used. If no overlapping version, of the dependency both container and plugin need, can be found, an error will be produced, since the negotiation failed.
Use no special scope for the dependencies, since you want them to be included if necessary into the container,

See:

https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/versionRanges.html

And:

https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html#pom-relationships-sect-version-ranges

Comment: So, if I mention that I have a dependency of junit of version>1.4 and the parent does not a dependency of this jar. Will it still give error or resolve by using the latest junit available?

Comment: If you don't use the scope provided, it will use the youngest dependency you defined in the plugin-pom. But be aware of snapshot in your maven-repository. This is best used for dependencies on artifacts you don't develop yourself, or you need to filter out snapshots explicitly.

Comment: Just finished testing this. Works well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your container and plugin projects use the same parent pom you could utilize the `<dependencyManagement>` section in the parent to define the common artifacts. This allows you to omit the version in the plugins `<dependencies>` section.

parent:

```
 <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

plugin/module:

```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>group-a</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact-a</artifactId>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

See https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html for further details.

Comment: That's a very nice approach and pretty much how we manage our product project. Unfortunately, my plugin project is not a part of the parent project. My intention is to have all dependencies in plugin project as a backup. So only if a dependency version is not available in parent/container project then only dependency version is picked up from my plugin project. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. So you can use a shared parent with the container project? If that is the case you could use the approach pointed out and specify the versions only of the artifacts not part of the dependencyManagement section of the parent in your plugin pom.xml.

Comment: This plugin project is developed separately. So its not a part of parent project hierarchy and does not include the parent pom.

Answer (score 0):

you can exclude it when you build a plugin project and add a dependency to maven.
This is an example. Dependency and main project have conflicted due to logging library. Below is to exclude log4j in dependency project.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>${zk.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

P/S: Added from my comments:
I have also developed a system which has a similar architecture with yours. I separate this system into 3 main parts: 1. Commons which contains common code and required maven dependencies, 2. The main project, 3. plugin project. You can refer this.

Comment: My plugin project contains 15-20 such dependencies. Excluding them, one by one would explode their pom.xml.

Comment: I have also developed a system which has a similar architecture with yours. I separate this system into 3 main parts: 1. Commons which contains common code and required maven dependencies, 2. Main project, 3. plugin project. You can refer this.

Comment: So, my container projects will have to exclude the 15 dependencies while adding plugin dependency. I know about this solution. I am looking for a solution(if possible) where the container does not have to exclude dependencies.

Comment: Check out this link, my solution is the second one. https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven

Comment: I have been through this link. It covers how you can catch dependency conflicts and not how the conflicts could be always resolved using container versions.